# Tensorflow: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to run the fine-tuning example from: https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html.

I'm using Pycharm,  and decreased the batch size to 1 in `training_args`:

```
per_device_train_batch_size=1,  # batch size per device during training
per_device_eval_batch_size=1,   # batch size for evaluation
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
line 585, in train self.args.eval_steps > 0
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

[image: error]

Comment: The error says `self.args.eval_steps` is null. And you should add the part of code related to this variable to debug why it is null.